# Как создать разные классы User под разные роли?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, авторизация, spring-security

Для авторизации используется Spring Security, соответственно у меня есть сущность User с полем `Set<Role> roles`. Из-за того, что пользователям с разными ролями нужны кардинально различающиеся наборы полей, я хочу сделать **User** общим абстрактным классом и наследовать от него конкретные классы под каждую роль: **SimpleUser**, **Admin** и т.д.

Spring Security использует для авторизации UserDetailsServicе, вот моя имплементация:

```
@Service("securityUserService")
public class SecurityUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    public SecurityUserService(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizedUser loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repository.getByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + email + " is not found");
        }
        return new AuthorizedUser(user);
    }
}
```

Если у меня будет несколько разных сущностей для пользователей, значит мне надо сделать несколько разных таблиц. К этим таблицам надо будет сделать разные репозитории. Вот тут и возникают проблемы. Если, допустим, авторизуется админ, то откуда сервис знает, в каком репозитории ему искать этого пользователя, если он знает только его имя?

Как мне правильно сделать так, чтобы у каждой роли был свой класс пользователя?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

Создаете суперкласс, например:

```
@Entity(name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    // etc...
}
```

Затем создаете конкретные сущности пользователей:

```
@Entity
public class SimpleUser extends User {
    // поля класса
}

@Entity
public class AdminUser extends User {
    // поля класса
}
```

Применяя такой паттерн вам достаточно иметь один репозиторий для сущности `User`, т.к. все наследуемые сущности будут храниться в таблице `users`

[См. документацию](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) и [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/337488/) на Хабре.